# Why does MEF2 not apply metadata attributes to all part exports?

Tags: c#, mef, mef2

I'm trying to port a collection of .NET Framework-based applications to .NET Core, and as part of this process I need to switch from using MEF1 to MEF2. I've been having a lot of difficulty wrapping my head around issues relating to MEF2 (though I've found [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13914256/strongly-typed-metadata-in-mef2-system-composition) really helpful), but I've recently stumbled across the reason behind one of them I've been having.

In particular, I have a number of classes that export metadata using a custom `ExportAttribute` and I would like to import them all in another class and filter them based on this metadata. This was all working fine in MEF1 but in MEF2 I ran up against problems such as "Export metadata for *x* is missing and no default value was supplied.".

More specifically, I annotate my exported classes like below:

```
[Export(typeof(IClientRequestProcessor<RelaySystemModel>))]
[TargetDevice("<<Foo>>")]
internal class RelaySystemClientRequestProcessor : IClientRequestProcessor<RelaySystemModel>
{
}
```

Then elsewhere, I will try to import them like this:

```
[ImportMany]
public IEnumerable<ExportFactory<IClientRequestProcessor<RelaySystemModel>, DeviceSpecific>> RelayRequestProcessors { private get; set; }
```

And then, on satisfaction of imports, attempt to filter them by metadata:

```
private static IEnumerable<ExportFactory<T, DeviceSpecific>> FilterForFoo<T>(IEnumerable<ExportFactory<T, DeviceSpecific>> items)
{
    return from it in items where it.Metadata.DeviceId == "<<Foo>>" select it;
}
```

Where `TargetDeviceAttribute` is defined as follows:

```
[MetadataAttribute, AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class)]
public class TargetDeviceAttribute : ExportAttribute, IDeviceSpecific
{
    public TargetDeviceAttribute(string deviceId)
    {
        this.DeviceId = deviceId;
    }

    public string DeviceId { get; private set; }
}
```

I've found that what's happening is that the *part* `RelaySystemClientRequestProcessor` corresponds with two *exports*: `IClientRequestProcessor<RelaySystemModel>`, which is the export I'm interested in and the interface I try to import the part with, and `RelaySystemClientRequestProcessor`. However, the "DeviceId" metadata is *only* associated with the latter and not the former, which isn't helpful.

[image: MEF2-exports]

There are several ways that I believe this could be resolved though I haven't fully tested:

1. Applying the attribute `ExportMetadata("DeviceId", "<<foo>>")` to all of my exported parts.
2. Changing the `TargetDeviceAttribute` to use the constructor `public TargetDeviceAttribute(string deviceId, Type exportType) : base(exportType)`.

I'm not in favour of these solutions; the former would be problematic in case I wanted to change the metadata key, and both would involve changing the way I export all my parts.

What I'm wondering is if MEF2 provides a way to export metadata like in MEF1: by creating a custom metadata attribute and having it apply that metadata to *all* exports associated with a part. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out I just needed to delete 6 characters. Instead of making `TargetDeviceAttribute` inherit from `ExportAttribute`, it should just inherit from `Attribute` instead:

```
[MetadataAttribute, AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class)]
public class TargetDeviceAttribute : Attribute, IDeviceSpecific
{
    public TargetDeviceAttribute(string deviceId)
    {
        this.DeviceId = deviceId;
    }

    public string DeviceId { get; private set; }
}
```

In the more general case, this means that any metadata that can be associated with multiple possible types but should ensure better static type safety/maintainability than just `ExportAttribute("foo", "bar")` should I suppose be done something like below:

```
public interface IMetadataExtension
{
    string Foo { get; }
}

public class MetadataExtension : IMetadataExtension
{
    public string Foo { get; set; }
}

[MetadataAttribute]
public class MetadataExtensionAttribute : Attribute, IMetadataExtension
{
    public MetadataExtensionAttribute(string foo)
    {
        Foo = foo;
    }

    public string Foo { get; }
}

[Export]
[MetadataExtension("bar")]
public class SomeExport
{

}
```